# K&R 1.6 Sample Code Displays Long Integers

Tags: c, arrays

Chapter 1.6 of K&R gives sample code for counting digits, white space, other characters.  What follows is their code, plus the return 0 line.

```
int c, i, nwhite, nother;
int ndigit[10];

nwhite = nother = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i);
    ndigit[i] = 0;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    if ( c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        ++ndigit[c - '0'];
    else if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
        ++nwhite;
    else
        ++nother;

printf("digits=");
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
printf(", white space = %d, other =%d\n",
    nwhite, nother);

return 0;
```

When I run this, whatever the input, I get a long string of integers (1-7 digits, some positive, some negative, all consistent regardless of input) for what the counts of 0-9 ought to be.  Process does return 0.

(Would copy and paste sample but am also having trouble with getting that to work in cmd despite following these instructions on [How to enable Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V for pasting in the Windows command prompt](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/25590/how-to-enable-ctrlv-for-pasting-in-the-windows-command-prompt).)

What's wrong?

Comment: You have an extra `;` that is screwing things up.

Comment: Because the first loop `for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i);` is ending by a `;`the ndigit array is not well-initialized. To prevent this missing, use `{ ... }` to mark the conditional block code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this part of your code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i);
    ndigit[i] = 0;
```

It does the same as this (I only split the first line to two lines and unindent you second line):

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    ;

ndigit[i] = 0;
```

So the `for` loop has the **empty body** - it only increases the variably `i` to the point when it reaches the value `10`.

So the next command

```
ndigit[i] = 0;
```

does this:

```
ndigit[10] = 0;
```

and it is totally different from your intent - you wanted to perform this:

```
ndigit[0] = 0;
ndigit[1] = 0;
ndigit[2] = 0;
.
.
ndigit[9] = 0;
```

As you didn't perform these 10 initializing assignments, values are - instead of zeroes - **undefined**, so they contain random (arbitrary) values.